# Nullpointerexception when togglebutton is clicked

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, togglebutton

I am trying to get a ToggleButton working but am having a few problems.
1. Its seems to revert back to the default value when it is clicked and I navigate to another screen.
2. I tried transferring its isChecked() value to another activity using SharedPreferences and it now crashes.

```
    <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/togBTN"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/homeBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
    android:text="Voice Alerts"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON" />
```

The above code is in my xml file.
The code below is the onClickListener code for it.

```
         case R.id.togBTN:
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
         editor.putBoolean("tgpref", tg.isChecked()); // value to store
         editor.commit();
     break;
     }
```

And this code is where I try to retrieve the value

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", true);  //default is true
    if (tgpref = true) //if (tgpref) may be enough, not sure
    {
      speakValue = true;
    }
    else
    {
     speakValue = false;
    }
```

This is what I am getting in the `Logcat`:

```
    02-21 14:49:09.587: W/dalvikvm(483): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40015560)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at ohalleran.stephanie.Traffic.SettingsActivity.onClick(SettingsActivity.java:45)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-21 14:49:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(483):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: I usually use a OnCheckedChangeListener for toggle buttons: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `==` **operator** instead of `=`.

Comment: Thanks. That helped.  I was also missing this line.   SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);  But now the activity that retrieves the value only picks up the default one, not the updated one.

Comment: also can use simple    if (tgpref)

Answer (score 1):

if (tgpref) is enough

a null pointer exception occurs when you have a statement of the form

A.B.C.D.E

either A is null
or A.B is null
or A.B.C is null
or A.B.C.D is null

something at the left of a dot is null.

Check line 45 of SettingsActivity.java, you will find your culprit there.